# Bootstrap - Set time to close automatically an alert?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3.2.0. I want to validate a form. I already could validate my form in case the username is empty, so the alert is displayed but disappears immediately, so the users are not going to be able to read the message. I don't know how to set a time to disappear automatically or leave it there without closing it.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="well bs-component">
        <form class="form-horizontal" name="login" method="post">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>L Torres Goldsmith</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">User:</label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="username" placeholder="Username">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">&nbsp;Keep me signed in
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="validateForm();">Submit</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="wronguser">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        var user = document.forms["login"]["username"].value;
        var html = "";
        if( user.trim() == "" )
        {
            document.getElementById("wronguser").style.display = "block";
            html = "<div class=\"alert alert-dismissable alert-warning\" id=\"wronguser\">";
            html += "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</button> ";
            html += "<h4>Warning!</h4>";
            html += "<p>Something went wrong.</p>";
            document.getElementById("wronguser").innerHTML = html;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Does anyone knows how to solve my problem?

Comment: Looking at your code I wouldn't expect the alert to disappear immediately. If anything I'd imagine it would stay there forever…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, your page is getting reloaded when you click the submit button. Change your javascript function to `return` some boolean value like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        var user = document.forms["login"]["username"].value;
        if( user.trim() == "" )
        {
            var html = "";
            document.getElementById("wronguser").style.display = "block";
            html = "<div class=\"alert alert-dismissable alert-warning\" id=\"wronguser\">";
            html += "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</button> ";
            html += "<h4>Warning!</h4>";
            html += "<p>Something went wrong.</p>";
            document.getElementById("wronguser").innerHTML = html;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

and add the `return` before the `validateForm()` in the onclick event to the submit button like this.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return validateForm();">Submit</button>
```

FYI: If you change the type from `submit` to `type="button"`; your page won't get reloaded.